# brew upgrade <package> does not update to the latest version

Tags: homebrew, wp-cli

I've noticed this happening a few times but this most recent instance is with `wp-cli` Running `brew upgrade wp-cli` does not download the latest version.

```
$ brew upgrade wp-cli
Error: homebrew/php/wp-cli 0.20.1 already installed

$ brew info wp-cli
homebrew/php/wp-cli: stable 0.20.1, HEAD
A set of command-line tools for managing WordPress installations.
http://wp-cli.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/wp-cli/0.20.1 (2635 files, 15M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/blob/master/Formula/wp-cli.rb
```

Note the version is `0.20.1`. When I check [the formula repo](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/blob/master/Formula/wp-cli.rb#L10), I see,

```
head "https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli.git"
```

When I check [that repo](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli), I see that the version in the master branch is [0.24.0](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/master/VERSION). `brew info` and `wp --version` both return `0.20.1`. Why isnt Homebrew grabbing the latest version? How do I force it to get the latest?

Comment: what if you run `brew update` first ?

Comment: Yep. That was it. I could have sworn I did that multiple times but apparently I didnt. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to run `brew update` first to force brew to update its list of formulae.